# FBML to PHP variable

Tags: php, fbml

hello how to set a value in php variables from fbml(facebook markup language)

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://domain.com/view/24></fb:comments-count>
```

please share your idea :)

Comment: I think they're after the comments count as a PHP var

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me. (Although it won't work this way)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is get the number of comments for a certain page. In that case you shouldn't do it via FBML but instead make a REST call: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/

You'll see that you can do a call along the lines of `https://api.facebook.com/method/fb:comments?access_token=https://api.facebook.com/method/fb:comments?access_token=FOO`

Comment: im using facebook comment plugin for my blog so now i would like to count a comment on that certain plugin...

example: `<fb:comments href="http://domain.com/view/4" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>`

to count: `<fb:comments-count href=http://domain.com/view/24></fb:comments-count>`

Comment: @Marcelius what you want isn't possible, because PHP runs on the server side and FBML does not. The way Ahmed shows is the only way to go.